# PHP in_array takes only last vlaue?

Tags: php

I am currently working on an order flow. I am not really a star in PHP coding, but trying this now;-)

```
if(isset($_SESSION["cart_item"]) && count($_SESSION["cart_item"])>0){
    if($configdetail->servicefeeapply==2){
        foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $key => $value) {
            $totalprice +=$value['itemprice'];
        }
        if(in_array('postal',$value['shipping'])){
            $shippingprice=str_replace(",",'.',$configdetail->servicefee);
        }
    }
    if($configdetail->servicefeeapply==1){
        foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $key => $value){
            if(in_array('postal',$value['shipping'])){
                $shippingprice +=str_replace(",",'.',$configdetail->servicefee);
            }
            $totalprice +=$value['itemprice'];
        }
    }
    if($post['paymentype']=='paypal'){
        $grandtotal = $totalprice+$shippingprice+$servicefee;
    }

    else{
        $grandtotal = $totalprice+$shippingprice;
    }
}
```

My problem now is, that the array in the session for 'shipping' can be "postal", "email" or "email,postal". But the code "in_array" takes always only the last run of the "foreach" function. So when I have in may basket the first article shipped by email and the second by postal, than I get the correct servicefee. But when I have the first article by postal and the second article by email, it takes only the array 'email' and I cannot show the servicefee.

Any ideas? I hope I have explained it enough.
Many thanks.

Comment: `$shippingprice[]=str_replace...` then outside the loop `echo array_sum($shippingprice);`?

Comment: You have 2 opening braces but 3 closing braces (making your snippet invalid code). According to indentation the `in_array` part is supposed to be within the loop, according to the braces it is outside. Can you fix that?

Comment: added the full code section. Now it should be correct. My problem is the first section, where I just wanna calculate the delivery cost one time. On option 2 delivery cost will be added to each article

Answer (score 0):

```
        if(isset($_SESSION["cart_item"]) && count($_SESSION["cart_item"])>0){
        foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $key => $value) {
            $totalprice +=$value['itemprice'];
        }
        foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $key => $value) {
            if(in_array('postal',$value['shipping'])){
                if($configres->servicefeeapply==2){
                    $shippingprice =str_replace(",",'.',$configdetail->servicefee);
                }
                else{
                    $shippingprice +=str_replace(",",'.',$configdetail->servicefee);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I think I made it with using a break;
Many thanks the help.